# how stringByEvaluatingJavaScript in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, uiwebview, appdelegate, swift3

## SOLVED

I used observer in ViewController

I have a iOS webview in Swift3 and need call Js function from AppDelegate.
The reason why is because i'm using push notifications, and when the user click on notification i need to pass the information from swift3 to JS.

This is the head of my ZhWebViewController

`class ZhWebViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
    func passNotificationToWebView(userInfo: AnyObject){
       let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: userInfo, 
       options:

       JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
       let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding:

       String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String
       self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: 
       "triggerNotificationClick(\ 
       (jsonString))")
   }
}`

This is how i declare my UIWebView

`@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!`

This is how i call JS functions, this way works!!!

`self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "someFunctionJS(\(jsonString))")`

This is head of my AppDelegate

`@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  var window: UIWindow? 
}`

**This is where i receive notification and here i want to call JS function**, i try call a function in ZHWebView and there try to send to JS, but i get fatal error.

`@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate{
   func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
      didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
      withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
      let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
      ZhWebViewController().passNotificationToWebView(userInfo: userInfo as 
      AnyObject)
      completionHandler()
   }
}`

Comment: Are you using a `UIWebView` or a `WKWebView`?

Comment: i'm using UIWebView, i edit my post to get things clear, pls help me!

Comment: What kind of fatal error is it? Please show the code that triggers the error and information about the error.

Comment: I edit the post again. The fatal erro is when i try to stringByEvaluatingJavaScript inside passNotificationToWebView. The error is: fatal erro: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: You create a new `ZhWebViewController` instance and call `passNotificationToWebView(...)` on this object. Among other things this will lead to your @IBOutlet webView being nil. You probably want to perform this call on your existing `ZhWebViewController` instance that was loaded from the storyboard.

Comment: Or you could push a new instance to your navigation controller, it depends on your app structure. But you should probably use `storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(...)` to create one. (Btw., this is really turning into a very different question, I'll update my answer with some info later.)

Comment: Thanks man!! I will search something about what you said, but if u post a detailed answer it's gonna be nice!

Comment: I would need to know if you use a storyboard (and how that looks like) or if you use xibs or set up everything using code. Probably not the latter, as I see an `@IBOutlet`.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

It seems I totally misunderstood your question. The question is not how to evaluate some JavaScript but how to get from your app delegate to your view controller. These should help you:

- [How to go directly to a specific View Controller if Notification has been opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39896631/how-to-go-directly-to-a-specific-view-controller-if-notification-has-been-opened)
- [What is correct way to notify view controller from AppDelegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165443/what-is-correct-way-to-notify-view-controller-from-appdelegate)

**Original answer:**

It depends on whether you are using a `UIWebView` or a `WKWebView`. The main difference evaluating JavaScript code between `UIWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript()` and `WKWebView.evaluateJavaScript()` is that the former call is
synchronous and the latter is asynchronous.

Compare

```
let webView: UIWebView = ...
let result = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "your javascript goes here")
```

with

```
let webView: WKWebView = ...
webView.evaluateJavaScript("your javascript goes here") { (result: Any?, error: Error?) in
    // handle completion
}
```

Please note the [UIWebView API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebview) states

> In apps that run in iOS 8 and later, use the WKWeb​View class instead of using UIWeb​View.
>   [...]
>   Although this method [stringByEvaluatingJavaScript] is not deprecated, best practice is
>   to use the evaluate​Java​Script(_:​completion​Handler:​) method of the WKWeb​View class instead.

Which is further emphasized by [WKWebView's API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview):

> **Important**
>   Starting in iOS 8.0 and OS X 10.10, use WKWebView to add web content to your app. Do not use UIWebView or WebView.

Comment: Man, ty for answering me! I edited my post to clearify things, i hope you can solve my problem.